# É correto chave estrangeira com campo nulo? PostgreSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Estava construindo um modelo entidade relacionamento (MER) de um banco de dados para uma associação rual, é um trabalho para materia de TABD. Porém me deparei com uma situação atípica para mim, um relacionamento 0,n para 0,1. Como podem ver na figura.[image: MER com o relacionameto da tabela pessoa com a tabela transacao 0,n e 0,1 respectivamente]

Acontece que nesse banco de dados nem sempre uma transação irá ter uma pessoa relacionada (a transação pode ser a saida de dinheiro com pagamento de contas por exemplo) e como a chave estrageira está na tabela transação isso implicaria em chaves estrangeiras nulas. A minha dúvida é se isso está correto? Chaves estrangeiras podem ser nulas? Caso não, porque?

Pesquisei em alguns lugares antes de perguntar aqui mas não havia concordância nas respostas.

Comment: Não sou especialista, vou deixar para alguém da área responder. Mas como desenvolvedor, não há problemas em deixar a chave estrangeira nula.
Provavelmente você poderá usar o campo `tipo` para diferenciar na hora de realizar as *queries* via aplicação. Caso o tipo seja *comum* (por exemplo, para mostrar que foi uma transação realizada por uma pessoa), então você saberá que há sempre um id_pessoa válido, não nulo. Caso o tipo não seja *comum* (por exemplo, realizada pelo próprio sistema), então você sabe que não há um id_pessoa válido.

Apenas uma visão de developer. Acompanharei a resposta.

Comment: Não tem lógica uma chave estrangeira ter valor nulo. Para além das chaves se poderem repetir, a foreign key se estiver ligada a uma tabela, não tem utilidade como ID.

Comment: Esse é o problema em minhas pesquisas para resolver essa questão. Sempre tem pessoas que dizem que não há problemas (essas dão respostas mais claras e coerentes) e pessoas que dizem que não tem lógica (porém, geralmente não há uma explicação para essa respostas). A pergunta para a segunda resposta é. Se não tem lógica, qual a maneira lógica de ligar duas tabelas nas quais as ligações não são obrigatórias em nenhum dos lados?

Comment: Não existe problema. Isto indica que o relacionamento é opcional. Caso fosse obrigatório você especificaria NOT NULL na chave estrangeira. O que você tem que verificar é se tal situação faz sentido em seu modelo dedados e, parece, você já fez tal verificação. Note que o que não faz sentido é você ter uma chave primária podendo conter NULL e, neste caso, os próprios SGBD não permitem tal construção.

Comment: Exemplo simples , o ENDEREÇO é opcional, mas se informado as FKs das tabelas UF, ESTADO,BAIRRO  tem de existir nss respectivas tabelas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com bases nos comentários dos autores

> Andrew Ribeiro & White

cheguei a seguinte conclusão:

Não faz sentido mesmo ter uma chave estrangeira nula, ao mesmo tempo que sim pode existir uma chave estrangeira nula porém ela se torna inútil pois o acesso a tuplas com chaves estrangeiras se faz justamento pelo valor dessa, se a mesma é nula não há como acessa-lá.

O erro no relacionamento que enviei é que não faz sentido existir uma transação sem que ela seja feita por uma pessoa, então o relacionamento deveria ser **(1,1)** para **(0,n)**.

Answer (score 0):

Faz sentido dependendo da aplicação do projeto, por exemplo um cliente compra numa loja e ele não quer fazer o cadastro dele na base de dados, ao efetuar a venda o valor da chave estrangeira para este cliente será nulo

Outro cliente com cadastro pode ir e colocar, a chave estrangeira para este cliente será um valor referente a este cliente na base de dados.

O que vai dar erro é referenciar um valor não existente na base de dados cliente, mas valor nulo não tem problema algum fiz este teste e deu certo

```sql
CREATE TABLE Cliente (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  nome VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Pedido (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  cliente_id INT DEFAULT NULL, 
  descricao VARCHAR(100),
  FOREIGN KEY (cliente_id) REFERENCES Cliente(id)
);

INSERT INTO Pedido(descricao)
VALUES('Pedido para cliente anônimo')

INSERT INTO Pedido(descricao, cliente_id)
VALUES('Cliente não existente', 2)

SELECT * FROM Pedido
```

O primeiro caso registrou sem problemas o segundo gerou erro :)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).